# Multiple users try to change one record at one time

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, database, nosql

We have too many records in database.

Multiple users try to change **one record at one time**.

How to prevent the change if the record has changed since read by the client, who wants to change it? (Another user has changed the record).

We can use any DBMS: SQL, NoSQL. But now we use mongodb.

Maybe I would get request:

```
IF (record has not changed) UPDATE
ELSE GET modified record
```

Comment: You should look into versioning

Comment: Versioning with the two queries to the database?   
There is no other way?

Comment: You have a field called, let's say for example, `_v` this holds a version number of the document, let's say `1`. When one user updates the row they will query for a document of their find key, again let's say `_id` with the `_v` key, `1`, if not document is found for update then the user is most likely trying to update an old and changed document, in this case bale them out, if not then update the document with the new `_v` key

Comment: But no apart from that there is no other way, well there could some more expensive and controlled versioning systems like MVCC but yeah,. there is no inbuilt easy method

Comment: Database systems like CouchDB/Couchbase have this feature built-in, so using a version in the object is a common pattern for handling data when there isn't a "LOCK" of some sort. MongooseJS even added a version field for preventing conflicting updates to arrays within MongoDB.

Comment: In support of @WiredPrairie Saying about Mongoose: http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943525537/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning though CouchDB actually uses MVCC which is slightly different

Comment: @Sammaye - yes, I was using "versioning" loosely. :)  "versioning" is a common pattern.

Comment: What kind of change are the two clients trying to make?

Comment: It is profiles (documents) of items with many fields. Clients change fields.